# angularjs ng-options advanced filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a custom filter for use with ng-options - but I already have a working filter setup for the other fields and can't seem to get the ng-options field to filter along with the others... Here's some code to explain:

This outputs the current filtered record count:

```
Records: {{(projects|filter:filter).length}} of {{projects.length}}
```

This is a general filter for search:

```
<input type="text" name="titleSearch" placeholder="Search Project Title" ng-model="filter.project_title">
```

This is my ng-options field that I'm trying to use to filter the results by State:

```
<select ng-model="stateOptions" ng-options="item.stateID as item.state for item in st_option">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
</select>
```

And this is my ng-repeat:

```
<div class="row grid collapse" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:filter | limitTo: paginationLimit()">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
       <span class="blueTxt">{{project.project_title}}</span><br>
          <span class="smTxt"><b>State:</b> {{project.state}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>County:</b> {{project.county}}<br>
            <b>Views:</b> {{project.project_views_total}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Bidders:</b> {{project.intent_to_bid_total}}</span>
            <span ng-hide="{{project.stateID}}"></span><span ng-hide="{{project.countyID}}"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the model:

```
[
  { projectID="390856", project_title="Water Pollution Control ...Upgrades, Las Vegas, NV", project_bid_date="<span class="redTxt hide...dTxt">04/28/2015</span>", more...}, 
  { projectID="390852", project_title="A&E Program Project Mana...nt Support Services, CA", project_bid_date="<span class="redTxt hide...dTxt">04/23/2015</span>", more...}, 
  { projectID="390851", project_title="REBID Fire Extinguishers...ion & Repair, Donna, TX", project_bid_date="<span class="redTxt hide...dTxt">04/10/2015</span>", more...}
]
```

Comment: I'm confused.... what is your custom filter? And what are you trying to use it on? And whats the actual issue?

Comment: David, sorry for the confusion!  I'm pretty new to Angular, I figured out all I had to do was change ng-model="stateOptions" to ng-model="filter.stateID" and it's not working as I wanted it to!